# Page content doesn't display when published but does when previewed as draft?

Tags: permalinks, pages, slug

I have a page called ecommerce which is published. It's not private or password protected. When I view the page I only see the page title in the body none of the content. If I preview the published page nothing shows up only the title.

If I set the status of the page to Draft and preview the page it'll display the content correctly.

If I change the permalink slug it will display fine when published. I had a page before with this name trashed and permanently deleted it. It seems something might have got left over in the database?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in WordPress version 3.4.2.

Bug report
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15665

It's been fixed and will roll out with WordPress version 3.5